# Should I use delegate to declare an anonymous asynchronous method?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, delegates

I'm looking for ideas about using `delegate` with `async` and `await`. Is it good or not? I've searched on Google but none of them are similar to mine.

I'm defining a method to change a message status (`isRead = true`) with SignalR:

```
enum MessageStatus
{
  Failure,
  Success
}

delegate Task<MessageStatus> MsgDelegate(string id);

public async Task ChangeMessageStatus(string id)
{
   string error = string.Empty;

   MsgDelegate msg = async (x) =>
   {
      try
      {
         using (var db = new VinaChanelDbContext())
         {
            var message = db.Messages.SingleOrDefault(m => m.Id == x);
            if (message != null)
            {
               message.IsRead = true;
            }
            return await db.SaveChangesAsync() > 0 ? 
                MessageStatus.Success : MessageStatus.Failure;
         }
      }
      catch (Exception e)
      {
         error = e.Message;
         return MessageStatus.Failure;
      }
   };
   switch (await msg(id))
   {
      case MessageStatus.Success:
         Clients.Caller.updateStatus(true);
         break;
      case MessageStatus.Failure:
         Clients.Caller.errorMessage(error);
         Clients.Caller.updateStatus(false);
      break;
   }
}
```

Is my code weird? Should I use it?

Comment: Why would you use a delegate there, when you only call the delegate once? Are you solving a problem with it, or just showing off? :-)

Comment: @GaryMcGill You mean I should use `delegate` if I call it twice or more times in a class, don't you?

Comment: well, I mean that delegates can be useful in some circumstances, but you seem to be looking for a reason to use them, rather than looking for a solution to a problem (which solution could be a delegate or something else). What's the problem you're trying to solve? I'll post an answer with how I would structure this code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why use a delegate? What's wrong with:

```
enum MessageStatus
{
    Failure,
    Success
}

public async Task ChangeMessageStatus(string id)
{
    string error = string.Empty;
    var status = MessageStatus.Failure;

    try
    {
        using (var db = new VinaChanelDbContext())
        {
            var message = db.Messages.SingleOrDefault(m => m.Id == id);
            if (message != null)
            {
               message.IsRead = true;
               if (await db.SaveChangesAsync() > 0)
               {
                 status = MessageStatus.Success;
               }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        error = e.Message;
    }

    switch (status)
    {
        case MessageStatus.Success:
            Clients.Caller.updateStatus(true);
            break;
        case MessageStatus.Failure:
            Clients.Caller.errorMessage(error);
            Clients.Caller.updateStatus(false);
            break;
    }
}
```

You might want to break that top part out into a private method, but I'm not sure why you would want to make it a delegate...

Comment: ya. I forgot that no need to declare a method inside a method in this case :)